# Seeing what flags are marked as invalid.

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

I am not sure if this is a bug, me not knowing where to look, or a feature request.

I know I can see all of my flags and see how many are valid versus invalid, but I have not been able to find any way to determine which are which.

It would sure be nice from a learning perspective to know what was considered invalid.

Comment: we are looking at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now see if a flag was invalid or not (though not which moderator dealt with the flag).  We'll continue improving the interface on that screen to clean things up a bit this week.

Comment: Yeah... No need to know what mod dealt with the flag. Thank You.